# How to open the gnome terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and would like to learn how bash command line works, but unable to access it. It seems that I can use Super-T to access monitor, but my keyboard does not have Super key. I use stand Windows keyboard which machine was in Windows. I would like to learn how to access bash command from Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you tried typing "gnome terminal" in the dash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search for "Terminal" in Unity's dash.

Alternatively, you can also access it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access tty1.

Answer (score 4):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Gnome Terminal
- Search for **Terminal** in Unity Dash

PS: Default Terminal of Ubuntu is Gnome Terminal